# How to set SQLite.NET page size in Xamarin app? PRAGMA page_size ignored

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, sqlite.net

After a lot of searching I haven't been able to find how to change the SQLite.NET Pagesize from the default of 4096. I have a Xamarin Forms PCL app with SQLite.NET Async PCL Nuget (and Twincoders Extensions but that's not relevant).

In the platform projects, SQLiteConnectionString does not appear to have a facility to set Pagesize.

My iOS code looks like this:

```
private static SQLiteConnectionString connectionString = new SQLiteConnectionString(Path.Combine(DatabaseFilePath, DatabaseFilename), false);
private static SQLiteAsyncConnection asyncConnection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(() => new SQLiteConnectionWithLock(new SQLitePlatformIOS(), connectionString));

public SQLiteAsyncConnection GetAsyncConnection() 
{
    return asyncConnection;
}
```

Help appreciated! If there is no way to do it, it would be good to know that too.

******** EDIT: ********

@Paul suggested using PRAGMA page_size, which I'm sure is the right idea. However SQLite.Net ignores a request to change the page_size, even though no table has yet been created and journalling mode is DEFAULT. At least in iOS. Unless my code is wrong:

In the Xamarin Forms PCL I have:

```
public interface ISQLite
{
    SQLiteAsyncConnection GetAsyncConnection ();
}
```

In my iOS project I have:

```
private static string DatabaseFilename = "MyDatabase.db3";

private static string DatabaseFilePath
{
    get
    {
        return (NSFileManager.DefaultManager.GetUrls
                    (NSSearchPathDirectory.LibraryDirectory,
                        NSSearchPathDomain.User) [0]).ToString();
    }
}

private static readonly SQLiteConnectionString connectionString = 
    new SQLiteConnectionString(Path.Combine(DatabaseFilePath, DatabaseFilename), false);
private static readonly SQLiteAsyncConnection asyncConnection = 
    new SQLiteAsyncConnection(() => new SQLiteConnectionWithLock(new SQLitePlatformIOS(), connectionString));

public SQLiteAsyncConnection GetAsyncConnection() 
{
    var syncTask = new Task (() =>
    {
        //asyncConnection.ExecuteAsync("PRAGMA journal_mode=DELETE");
        asyncConnection.ExecuteAsync ("PRAGMA page_size=1024"); // Has no effect on page size
    });
    syncTask.RunSynchronously();
    return asyncConnection;
}
```

This executes without error but does not change the page size.

All ideas welcome!

******** FURTHER EDIT: ********

Adding VACUUM had no effect either:

```
asyncConnection.ExecuteAsync ("PRAGMA page_size=1024; vacuum");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the pragma statement as described here:

http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_page_size

EDIT: this may be an iOS specific problem. Digging deeper I find:
http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html
*It is not possible to change the database page size after entering WAL mode, either on an empty database or by using VACUUM or by restoring from a backup using the backup API. You must be in a rollback journal mode to change the page size.*

and here, it looks like you may be in WAL mode:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1809/_index.html
*... the default journaling mode for Core Data SQLite stores was changed to Write-Ahead Logging (WAL) in iOS 7 and OS X Mavericks.*

You might try "PRAGMA journal_mode=DELETE;" before setting page size.

Comment: That's highly illuminating, Paul, thanks. I wasn't sure, though, where to use the pragma.

Comment: In the iOS project I used asyncConnection.ExecuteAsync("PRAGMA page_size = 1024"); but it had no effect, page size was still 4096. I also tried that in the Forms PCL project, no effect there either.

Comment: By the way I made sure my async call was awaited.

Comment: Was this condition true: "The page_size pragma will only cause an immediate change in the page size if it is issued while the database is still empty, prior to the first CREATE TABLE statement."? There have been minor bugs in the API before, but I doubt they would miss this one.

Comment: Yes, this is before anything is done with the database. My updated iOS code (having no effect):    
    public SQLiteAsyncConnection GetAsyncConnection() 
    {
        var syncTask = new Task (() =>         {             asyncConnection.ExecuteAsync ("PRAGMA page_size = 1024");         } );         syncTask.RunSynchronously();           return asyncConnection;     }

Comment: Also I made sure there was no pre-existing database: 'Reset contents and settings' in the iOS simulator.

Comment: Paul, re journal_mode, I found that the database already had journal_mode set to DELETE by default. I guess this is because this Nuget version of SQLite.NET differs from the Core Data SQLite. Just the same I tried setting it to DELETE explicitly, no effect. To verify the PRAGMA syntax, I tried temporarily setting it to WAL mode and it did set it to WAL. So I'm confident that connection.ExecuteAsync("PRAGMA page_size = 1024") is the right syntax. It's just ignored. Will raise this as an issue. Will also edit my original post. Many thanks for the help.

Comment: Bug report posted here:[link]( https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL/issues/128)

Comment: I want to know how this turns out since I will be doing a xamarin app in future. I think there is only one sqlite engine on iOS, provided by Apple.

Comment: I'll post the outcome here. What I don't quite get is, in SQLite.Net the database file is not created until the first CreateTable is executed. The first CreateTable creates the database. And we are not allowed to create a table until after setting page size and vacuuming. So the idea of vacuuming something that doesn't exist yet seems puzzling. Maybe I'm missing something amazingly obvious. :)

Comment: It's been confirmed that currently it's not possible to change the page size in SQLite.Net PCL. See bug report link above.

Comment: I believe there is more than one sqlite.net. The one I used a few years back had pragma statements implemented. I am unsure of the forking that has taken place.

Comment: Yes, @Paul. SQLIte.Net PCL is a fork off SQLite-Net.

Comment: fyi have been advised there are no plans to support page_size in the PCL (NuGet) version.